# Fetching Date of upcoming specified days

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uilocalnotification, nscalendar

I want to schedule UILocal Notifications and want them to be repeated on particular days specified by the user.The user specifies a particular date and then specifies the days on which he wants to repeat the same notification.

How do i fetch the dates from the specified days after user selection.I know i will have to fire multiple local notifications for that purpose.

Please help

Thanks,

Aditya

Comment: Does your question pertain to the obtaining of NSDate objects from a calendar/date picker, or the creation of a recurring UILocalNotification?

Comment: i want to create recurring UILocalNotifications for the days selected...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the creation of a `UILocalNotification` object only provides the option to recur on a single calendar unit. For example, you can have a notification that repeats every hour, or every day, or every weekday, etc. There is no way *without a little effort* to create a notification that repeats every Tuesday and Thursday.

**That having been said:** you can provide each `UILocalNotification` with a custom `NSDictionary`, assigned to the userInfo property on the object. If I were you, I would create a custom structure that contains a little bit more information about the notification, and store it in the dictionary. If you wanted it to be simple, it could just be a class containing 7 booleans, one for each day of the week.

As an example, you could create a `UILocalNotification` that repeats daily, with the above structure whose boolean values for Tuesday and Thursday are YES, and all other days are NO.

When your local notification fires, and you respond to it via the method:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocationNotification:(UILocationNotification *)notification
```

You can retrieve this userInfo dictionary from the notification, take a closer look at the underlying repeat, and ignore the notification if the boolean value for the current day is `NO`.